# Releasing allocated heap to OS

Tags: c, windows, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have read a bit on _heapmin after seeing that it does not work, and found out it's not documented right for some reason and the function actually does do nothing.

So is there any way to release the freed heap memory back to the OS? My app is a DLL that allocates and releases quite a bit of memory and also does so only when necessary, but it's necessary quite a lot and I cannot force the process it is loaded in to just restart whenever too much memory was allocated.

So is there anything I can do on Windows specifically?

Comment: Perhaps allocating your memory in a private heap would help, in that you could then free the private heap (via `HeapDestroy()`) when you're done.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/heap-functions